# How to specify the default value for nested property?

Tags: java, spring-boot

The following code throws NPE when I don't specify value for `acme.security.roles`:

```
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties("acme")
public class AcmeProperties {

    private final Security security;

    public AcmeProperties(Security security) {
        this.security = security;
    }

    public Security getSecurity() {
        return security;
    }

    public static class Security {

        private final List<String> roles;

        public Security(@DefaultValue("USER") List<String> roles) {
            this.roles = roles;
        }

        public List<String> getRoles() {
            return roles;
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(AcmeProperties.class)
public class MyConfiguration {

@Bean HttpClientConnectionManager httpClientConnectionManager(AcmeProperties acmeProperties) {

        Security security = acmeProperties.getSecurity();

        security.getRoles(); // throws NPE

        return new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to make spring boot instantiate `Security` object with default `roles` value? Should I use `@DefaultValue` and SPEL somehow to make it work?

Comment: why not just do this `private List<String> roles = Lists.newArrayList("USER")`. It will default to this value if nothing is found in properties file

Comment: In such case I would have to use `@DefaultValue("USER")` anyway to make spring boot generate spring-configuration-metadata.json with default value for `roles`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This should work.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "acme")
public class AcmeProperties {

    private Security security;

    public Security getSecurity() {
        return security;
    }

    public void setSecurity(Security security) {
        this.security = security;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initDefaultValues() {
        if(security == null) {
            security = new Security();
        }
    }
}
```

Security class will look like this

```
public class Security {

    private List<String> roles = Lists.newArrayList("USER");

    public List<String> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(List<String> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Well I know that I can achieve desired effect with mutable classes. But how to achieve the same with immutable?

Answer (score 0):

Since Spring Boot 2.2.7 it's possible to add `@DefaultValue` (with no arguments) to the `security` constructor parameter:

```
public AcmeProperties(@DefaultValue Security security) {
    this.security = security;
}
```