# @ConfigurationProperties with @Bean doesn't load defaults from classpath

Tags: java, spring-boot, configurationproperties

I'm facing following problem with `@ConfigurationProperties` placed on `@Bean`.The configuration is placed into application.yml within the library jar by default:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
public class MyConfiguration {

    @ConfigurationProperties("myprefix")
    @Bean
    public MyConfigProperties configProperties(){
       return new MyConfigProperties();
    }
}
```

MyConfigProperties.java - simple pojo

```
public class MyConfigProperties {
   private String myproperty;

public String getMyproperty( ...
public void setMyproperty( ...
}
```

application.yml

```
myprefix:
   myproperty: defaultValue
```

From the `@SpringBootTest` in the same project it works just fine. But if I use the library from another project, I always need to provide the `myprefix.myproperty` even the `defaulValue` would work fine for me.

My expectation is, the `defaultValue` should be taken from the application.yml provided within the jar, if no properties with higher precedence given.

Am I doing something wrong?

Kind regards,

Gena

Comment: check my answer here. It might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60935878/how-to-specify-the-default-value-for-nested-property/60939255?noredirect=1#comment107821031_60939255

Comment: Hi and thank you for the hint! But i think, this is suspect to use `@PostConstruct` or `@DefaultValue` for such usecase. It did work just fine with `@Value` and i mean, it should work with `@ConfigurationProperties` as well. The consern is to provide default application.yml/application.properties within the jar containing eg. evaluation license or other meaningful defaults.

Comment: @GenaBatalski, have you tried @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="myprefix") ?